# Java ArrayList subclass extraction

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, simulation

I'm creating an application where I use genetic algorithm (not implemented yet) to make creatures follow food and avoid obstacles.
I have in my simulation class (where the magic happens) an arraylist where all the creatures are stored. To be noted the arraylist is full of abstract class  objects whereas my creatures are all a subclass of `Creature`.

My question is: how can I make another ArrayList or similar where i can iterate over the arraylist and extract a particular subclass? I had a look and it seems there is no way for me to do so because of how java Collections work. Is there any kind of workaround or some library that could make this possible for me?

It is important for me to have separate lists because I need to apply behaviours to different kind of creature and weigh them according to the "dna" of the creature.
GitHub repository for the whole project: https://github.com/Jamesinvi/Animosity/tree/master/Animosity

I tried this but I get a list of all creatures because they are all of the Creature class

```
//in PSEUDOCODE i would like to do this:
new ArrayList newlist=new ArrayList<Creature>();
for(Creature old:oldList){
    if (old instanceof CreatureSubclass){
        newlist.add(old);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I am a student so forgive me if this is kind of a stupid question but I am struggling a bit with this. Thanks for the help :)

```
ArrayList <Creature>oldlist=new ArrayList<Creature>();
ArrayList <Creature>newlist=new ArrayList<Creature>();
for(int i=0;i<oldlist.size();i++){
    if (oldlist.get(i) instanceof CreatureSubclass){
        newlist.add(oldlist.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: You tried this but you... what? Make that code real Java code that compiles, and you'll have your answer (The visitor pattern would be cleaner, but you can start with that)

Comment: *...iterate over the arraylist and extract a particular subclass...* - why do you wish to do that? I ask because this is often an indication of a design fault. You should be able to add enough functionality to the objects themselves so that you don't need to do this.

Comment: my creatures have a method that calculates steering vectors according to weights. i pass to the method all the creatures i wish to calculate the forces of. Having separate lists means i can give more importance to the force generated towards a creature of a certain class than one from another. @OldCurmudgeon

Comment: *I tried this but I get a list of all creatures because they are all of the Creature class*: no, you didn't try this, since this code does not compile. Post what you **actually** tried.

Comment: @JamesKarran Maybe you can change your *calculate steering vectors* method in your *creature of a certain class* so it gives them more importance to the generated force.

Comment: @JBNizet adding the real code would mean posting all of the creature subclasses and the simulation main code...i don't think that is necessary : i understand WHY it doesnt work i just would like to know if you guys know another solution or workaround

Comment: No. You would just need to post the same snippet, but containing Java code that compiles, rather than pseudo-code that doesn't. I don't think you understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @JBNizet added the snippet :)

Comment: Your code works. But you're creating a list of Creature, instead of a list of CreatureSubclass. So you end up with a list that indeed contains only CreatureSubclass instances, but the compiler has no clue, since you didn't use the right type. Use `List<CreatureSubclass> newlist = new ArrayList<>();`, and cast the element: `newlist.add((CreatureSubclass) oldlist.get(i));`. Also, learn about the for each loop.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you! i do know about the  each for loop and i am changing some of the loops in the program to make it more readable :)

Comment: @JBNizet does the casting work for you? it seems  to me it's not working even though the compiler is not unhappy with it. It could be me being an idiot though: if didnt test this can i ask you to do so otherwise i'll post my updated code again :)

Comment: It can't possibly fail, since you just checked that the element is an instance of CreatureSubclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally agree with OldCurmudgeon. You should not extract the subclass.

If you really want to do that, one ugly method is to add a string as a member variable to Creature class called flag. So you could use the string comparison instead of instance of which is very dangerous.

```
if (oldCreature.flag.equals("SmallCreature"))
{
    newList.add(oldCreature); // another possible error: do you need a new copy or just reference?
}
```

And you could consider use enum class instead of string, which would also be a feasible and simple solution.

```
public enum CreatureName{SmallCreature, LargeCreature}
```

And again if you want to apply different behaviors onto the different kinds of the subclass (dna), do you have ever considered the design patterns like strategy or abstract class? The visitor pattern may be a good one mentioned by JB Nizet. But it may be overkill for this question.

Comment: ok i guess i will try changing my creature method to accept the whole list and then figure out what to do :) . Thanks for the help